# ASP.NET Create directory with current user permissions

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, wcf

I want to create a directory on a network path from a WCF web service. This web service is hosted under a site that uses Windows authentication. However, when I try to create the folder with "Directory.Create", I get an access denied. When I check "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name", I can see my own user account, but I guess it is not the one used to create the folder, as, when I do "System.Environment.UserName", I see another value.

I tried to put "`<identity impersonate="true" />`" in the main web.config of the web site but then, nothing works anymore.

So my question is, is it possible to create the directory using the permissions of the currently logged user ?

As a precision, I'm calling the webservice through AngularJS and I configured my "$httpProvider" to pass the credentials ("`$hp.defaults.withCredentials = true;`").

**EDIT:**

I added "`<identity impersonate="true" />`" to the web.config placed in the folder that contains my web service and now, "System.Environment.UserName" contains the correct credential but still, I guess the access denied. I tried the same command from a console application and it works. I really don't get it...

**EDIT 2**

If I changed the "identity" element to "`<identity impersonate="true" username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD" />`", then it works, but I don't want to fill these fields...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the network folder is on another server, you're either going to have to impersonate credentials that has access to it or whoever the apppool is running as will need permissions to write to that folder.

We typically have the app-pool running as a domain account in IIS.  You can tailor the permissions as you see fit then (assuming both servers are on the same domain and, you don't have to store passwords this way, whoever manages your IIS would handle that).  If the site just needs to write (but not read) you could give it write permissions but not read.

Comment: What's the purpose of writing  "`<identity impersonate="true" />`" if it does not solve this kind of issue ?

Comment: That is supposed to pass along identity from IIS.  To ensure your code is being run like that, I would write a file out to the site (if it has permissions) and check who the owner is on that file (because that owner will be the same person it's trying to write as to the network share).  If you see something like "network service" or "iusr_blablabla" then we know something has gone awry but at least it gives us a direction to look.

Comment: Check the documentation out here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx There is a blob at the bottom that reads "If the application resides on a UNC share, ASP.NET always impersonates the IIS UNC token to access that share unless a configured account is used. If you provide an explicitly configured account, ASP.NET uses that account in preference to the IIS UNC token.".  That would explain the behavior you're seeing.